# Spring returning a big String of data instead of List when using OneToMany

Tags: java, spring

Update: I tried returning null in Post entity from getAuthor() and getTopic() and that seems to have fixed it, but now the problem is I don't know who the author of a Post is... Would it be a smarter idea to just use `String usernameOfAuthor` instead of `Account author`?

I have Post entity and a Topic entity, and I want to set it up so that one Topic can have many Posts and many Posts can be in one Topic.. Here's my code for that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="topic")
public class Topic extends TimeStampModel {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String codeName;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "topic")
    private List<Post> posts;

//getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post extends Likeable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="topic_id", nullable = false)
    private Topic topic;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account author;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
    List<Comment> topLevelComments;

//getters and setters
}
```

Now when I run this code, and I make a request to get all topics, this is what it looks like in my browser: [image: example]

If I remove the `mappedBy='topic'` and the `@JoinColumn(name="topic_id", nullable = false)`, everything works fine, and I get a List of Topics as a return and that is good, but then my Posts don't work, none of my Topics have posts... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't described a problem and screen getAllTopics output has a bad quality.

Comment: @SeydazimovNurbol Did you read the post? I am expecting a List as a response to my request and instead I am getting a large String with repeating data. Also you can click on the image to make it larger..

Comment: Could you provide details of you database design? How do the tables and column datatypes look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add @JsonBackReference to prevent Jackson (json) infinite recursion problem.

```
@JsonBackReference 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="topic_id", nullable = false)
private Topic topic;
```